# Infinite loop when I am using array.splice

Tags: javascript

```
   for (let i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
     if(waypoints[i].id.toString() === data.waypoint.waypoint.toString()) {
        if(data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'above') {
            waypoints.splice(i, 0, waypoint)
        }
        if(data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'below') {
            waypoints.splice(i+1, 0, waypoint)
        }
        if(data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'none') {
            waypoints.push(waypoint)
        }
     }
    }
```

I have ann array called waypoints which has some objects. Every object has an id.
On the front end I have the list of these objects displayed and every object has 2 buttons Add Above and Add Below. For 'none' is other story and that works. But every time is 'above' or 'below' I get an infinite loop. I think it passes the limit of the array but it shouldn't. I am telling him to find the 'waypoint' with that id (data.waypoint.waypoint) and then insert according to the case 'above' or 'below'.

I can't find a solution, there was another thread about this but the answer was not clear.

Comment: could be that you are modifying the same array you are iterating

Comment: I was trying with a copy too, same results

Comment: You are add elements to the array, and iterating on the array length which will be increased during the loop, so the loop never ends. You can either a) not do that which I recommend: build a new array rather than modifying the original in place or b) increment `i` enough when you add something to skip past the new element.

Comment: I understand, how can fix this?

Comment: I mean I can find the index using array.findIndex and then just waypoints.splice(index, 0, waypoint) ?

Comment: @CalinOnaca that would have abysmal performance and is even worse of a solution than the other two I mentioned.

Comment: @CalinOnaca When you tried to copy the array, did you do something like **copy = waypoint**? Although it may sound strange, that technique will not actually duplicate the array properly. But **copy = […waypoint]** should work fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I will try with copy = [...waypoint]

Comment: that worked thank you so much I will update the question with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
const copy = [...waypoints] // duplicate the array

for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) { // iterate through the duplicate array

   if (waypoints[i].id.toString() === data.waypoint.waypoint.toString()) {
        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'above')
            waypoints.splice(i, 0, waypoint)

        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'below')
            waypoints.splice(i + 1, 0, waypoint)
        
        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'none')
            waypoints.push(waypoint)
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ ‘s suggestion, an even simpler solution is to make a **variable** to signify the array’s length. You could write something similar this:

```
const copy = waypoints.length // copy the array length

for (let i = 0; i < copy; i++) { // iterate through the length

   if (waypoints[i].id.toString() === data.waypoint.waypoint.toString()) {
        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'above')
            waypoints.splice(i, 0, waypoint)

        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'below')
            waypoints.splice(i + 1, 0, waypoint)
        
        if (data.waypoint.where.toString() === 'none')
            waypoints.push(waypoint)
    }
}
```

Comment: @CalinOnaca no problem! I’ve struggled with a similar problem to yours in the past, so it’s a pleasure for me to share the solutions when others get stuck too :)

Comment: Don't need to duplicate the array. That you need is a variable with the initial length......... eg. let le = waypoints.length  and use it> for (let i = 0; i < le; i++) { .....

Comment: My initial array length is 3 and after everything is done it becomes 5, not 4 as it should be, do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: @CalinOnaca hm..  that’s strange. I’m not sure why that would happen. Are you sure the array length is going weird at this exact point of code? It could be changing in another area of your code that I haven’t seen..